# Running selenium with firefox without a display

Tags: linux, firefox, selenium

Is there any way to run a selenium python script that's supposed access a webpage using firefox but without a display? I am running this on an ubuntu VPS and I have no way of accessing a display unless I install ubuntu-desktop with VNC which takes up a LOT of memory.

So is there a solution to running firefox without a display on an ubuntu server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb ? Virtual frame buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting via ssh with the -X switch. That will enable you to use X applications remotely. It will be a little slow but it should be usable for a lot of applications.

```
ssh -X you@yourserver
$ firefox &
```

Edit: I just checked it out on one of my ubuntu servers. It required ~140MB of extra deps to install firefox (no ubuntu-desktop, or xserver).